# Modem and wifi connection

Tags: home-networking

I was recommended to purchase a Linksys Velop and a Netgear CM700 modem to connect my entire house. The modem I have seen including the CM700 has only one Ethernet connection.  My old surfboard modem/router has four. My desktop is connected directly to the old surfboard. Will a splitter, a hub or switch be useful for what I want to do?

Comment: Is your house large? If it isn't extremely big, you can just get a Netgear, or any other brand, modem/wifi router combo. For example, a [Netgear C6300](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00J65WQHU/?coliid=I1IS4VB836F1JD&colid=HVT1UUHVKCF4&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it)

Comment: It is ~2600 sq ft.

Comment: A modem/wifi router combo will work just fine for you. If for some reason the C6300 would be incompatible with your ISP, you could get the CM700, a small Netgear switch, and a wireless router. You could use the Velop, but the point of that product is for making a mesh network to help cover dead areas in a home. If you only have one, then you're only using it as a router. You can get an 802.11ac wifi router for less than $100.

Comment: @DrZoo: Does the Velop act as an IP router by default, or is it only a WiFi access point?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need 1 Ethernet cable to your Desktop from the Velop Mesh Device, then you should be fine without an switch/hub. Because the Both the Tri-Band, and Dual-Band have 2 Ethernet ports on the bottom or back of the unit.

Basically this is how you'll set it up.

Netgear CM700 is your modem > To

Your Velop unit. It has 2 Ethernet Ports on the back or bottom  > To

Your Desktop.

**Tri-Band**

[image]

**Dual-Band**

[image]

NOTE: If for whatever reason you're going to need to use **more than 1 port** from the Velop unit. You'll need to buy a network switch, and route all of your hardline connections through the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ethernet **switches** are used for this purpose. The four LAN ports you see on most home routers are also a built-in switch.

In the past, hubs were also used with older Ethernet types (in the 10 Mbps days), but they have major downsides compared to switches, and just outright cannot be used for 1 Gbps Ethernet. (Note: Most modern products labelled as "Ethernet hubs" are actually switches.)

There is no such thing as an "Ethernet splitter". (There are adapters allowing you to run two *independent* 10/100 Mbps Ethernet links over a single cable, but you cannot just connect that to a single port: there needs to be an opposite adapter on the other end, separating it into two ports again. Plus, those too are impossible to use with Gigabit Ethernet.)